# regex capture groups returning as null after an OR operator

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)px|\\bbackground\\s*:\\s*#([0-9A-Fa-f]+)").matcher(myString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Example data:
`myString = width:17px;background:#555;float:left;` will produce `null`.
What I wanted:

```
matcher.group(1) = 17
matcher.group(2) = 555
```

I've just started using regex on Java, any help?

Comment: You don't any captured group 2 in your pattern.

Comment: You're requesting `String` parse, so you should use a `StringTokenizer` or another classto parse it instead of a regex.

Comment: Why this question is voted down?

Comment: I thought `([0-9A-Fa-f]+)` was the second capture group. Rookie mistake? Sorry I'm new to regex.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this other than "or" means .... "or".

Comment: @meiryo.. You have used a pipe - `|`, which means `or`. So, your pattern `this|that` means `this or that`. So, if `this` is found, `that` is ignored, and if `that` is found `this` ignored. So, both the capture group are not the part of same pattern.

Comment: @RohitJain So I should be using AND OR?

Comment: @meiryo.. No, just print `matcher.group(1)`, and instead of `if (matcher.find())` use `while (matcher.find())`. And you will get all the numbers.

Comment: As written, you have to apply your regex twice to the string, once to capture the width, once to capture the background (making sure that the width data is skipped on the second iteration).  You also have the problem that you can't tell whether it just matched a width or a background because you've not captured that information.  If the fields in the string were in the reverse order, you'd have no idea that the background came before the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to split things a bit up.

Instead of building one large regex (maybe you want to add more rules into the String?) you should split up the string in multiple sections:

```
String myString = "width:17px;background:#555;float:left;";
String[] sections = myString.split(";"); // split string in multiple sections
for (String section : sections) {

  // check if this section contains a width definition
  if (section.matches("width\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)px.*")) {
    System.out.println("width: " + section.split(":")[1].trim());
  }

  // check if this section contains a background definition
  if (section.matches("background\\s*:\\s*#[0-9A-Fa-f]+.*")) {
    System.out.println("background: " + section.split(":")[1].trim());
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. Having | (or) in the regexp is usually confusing so I've added two more matchers to show how I would do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "width:17px;background:#555;float:left";

    int matcherOffset = 1;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bwidth\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)px|\\bbackground\\s*:\\s*#([0-9A-Fa-f]+)").matcher(myString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("found something: " + matcher.group(matcherOffset++));
    }

    matcher = Pattern.compile("width:(\\d+)px").matcher(myString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("found width: " + matcher.group(1));
    }

    matcher = Pattern.compile("background:#(\\d+)").matcher(myString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("found background: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```